# Dynamically add link to javascript generated AJAX HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I am generating HTML tables with javascript, populating the cells with data from an AJAX file.  I want to dynamically add links to certain cells.  Linking to myfile.php.  I'll let the PHP deal with the requests.

Every cell should have a link.  All linking back to my php file, something like

```
<a href="myfile.php?data=whatever_the _cell_value_is">Click here</a>
```

But, how can I add the links?

Take this simple example.  Only two fields.  So I want each cell to have a unique link back to my server so I can then serve another JSON file for expanded info.

I was thinking of a conditional, depending on the key.

```
 if(index == 'username') {

    ADD THE LINK
 } else { 
    .....
 }
```

I am having trouble with the correct syntax, I having trouble getting it to work.  All these years, I never programmed Javascript.

See my code below.

```
<HTML>
    ...

    <script>
    var data = [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "username": "foo",
            "email": "hhh@hhh.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "username": "foobarbam",
            "email": null
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "username": "bar",
            "email": "bar@proton.me"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "username": "bam",
            "email": null
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "username": "snoopy",
            "email": null
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "username": "rogerwaters",
            "email": "barbam@proton.me"
        }
   ];



   var keys = [];

   document.write("<table><tr>");
   var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].username + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].email + "</td>");
        
        $('table').append(tr);
    }

    document.write("</table>");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Which cell should have the link? And how should the code know what URL to put in the link? Does that depend on something in the data item bring processed? You didn't really explain clearly what the outcome should be.

Comment: My bad, just edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *every* cell should contain a link, then you don't need any kind of conditional. You can just amend the HTML so it outputs a link each time.

Demo:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "3",
    "username": "foo",
    "email": "hhh@hhh.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "username": "foobarbam",
    "email": null
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "username": "bar",
    "email": "bar@proton.me"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "username": "bam",
    "email": null
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "username": "snoopy",
    "email": null
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "username": "rogerwaters",
    "email": "barbam@proton.me"
  }
];

document.write("<table><tr>");
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td><a href='myfile.php?data=" + data[i].username + "'>" + data[i].username + "</a></td>");
  tr.append("<td><a href='myfile.php?data=" + data[i].email + "'>" + data[i].email + "</a></td>");

  $('table').append(tr);
}

document.write("</table>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I figured my own workaround.  I'll edit my post and add my code.  Cheers.

Comment: Ah good, if you found your own solution you can add it as an alternative Answer too, questions are allowed multiple answers